# Ethers and Web3-React: Cannot estimate gas when trying to connect with contracts deployed on testnet and using Alchemy as node provider

Tags: rinkeby, gas-estimate, ethers.js, hardhat, typescript

I'm trying to connect with contracts deployed on the Rinkeby testnet using a node provider. When I was testing using hardhat as a local node, the contracts are called with no problem, but when I change to Rinkeby, I get an error `cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"code":-32000,"message":"execution reverted"}, method="call"` for all the contract functions I'm trying to call. I've seen forums saying that it's usually due to the node being unable to estimate the gas limit and that I should manually set it.

By the way, Web3-React and Ethers.js don't contradict each other despite the naming. Web3-React is simply a React state machine that dynamically keeps track of my current wallet address, chain id, and browser provider `Web3Provider`, which I also use to create Contract instances using its signer. I use Ethers to create the Contract instances, format and parse data, and use its `getDefaultProvider` method to connect me to Alchemy. I made sure my rinkeby account had ether, and to change my local contract address variables to those of the ones deployed.

I'm also honestly a bit confused on what to do next, shouldn't the app suffice with just the `Web3Provider` instance from Web3-React? I've read on a lot of tutorials but nothing that explains something like this specifically.

Some example code below to show how the project is structured:

I've been keeping track of variables from Web3-React globally via React Context like this:

```
const value = useMemo<ContextWallet>(
    () => ({
      ...
      isActive: web3React.active,
      account: web3React.account ?? undefined,
      chainId: web3React.chainId,
      library: web3React.library,
      ...
      connect,
      disconnect,
      ...
    }),
```

For clarification, `web3React.library` essentially returns `new Web3Provider(window.ethereum)` where `Web3Provider` is imported from `@ethersproject/providers`. `web3React.account` returns from the ethereum request `eth_accounts`, `web3React.chainId` is from the request `eth_chainId` or `net_version`, and `web3React.isActive` lets us know whether the connection is working or not.

To create a contract instance via a signer I use the following functions:

```
export function getContract(address: string, ABI: any, library: Web3Provider, account?: string): Contract {
  if (!isAddress(address) || address === AddressZero) {
    throw Error(`Invalid 'address' parameter '${address}'.`)
  }

  const contract = new Contract(address, ABI, getProviderOrSigner(library, account) as any)
  return contract
}

export function getProviderOrSigner(library: Web3Provider, account?: string): Web3Provider | JsonRpcSigner {
  return account ? getSigner(library, account) : library
}

function getSigner(library: Web3Provider, account: string): JsonRpcSigner {
  return library.getSigner(account).connectUnchecked()
}
```

As for the provider to Alchemy, I did it like this but I don't really know what to do next:

```
getDefaultProvider(getNetworkName(Number(CHAIN_ID)), { alchemy: ALCHEMY_API_KEY })
```

The next snippet is an example of how I call a contract function:

```
const depositEth = async (amount: number, gas: any) => {
    setLoading(true)
    if (!farmContract || !vaultContract) return
    try {
      const tx = await farmContract.depositEth({
        value: parseEther(amount),
        gasPrice: gas,
      })
      await tx.wait()
      await farmContract.once('EthDeposited', (sender, amount, tx) => {

        // At this point, the transaction should have been mined already
        console.log('EthDeposited event detected: ', tx)
        wallet.reload()
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error depositEth ', err)
      wallet.reload()
    }
  }
```

Can someone offer some suggestions or advice on how to solve this step?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should put `gasLimit` either manually or dynamically in last argument of SC method call.

```
 const tx = await farmContract.depositEth({
    gasLimit: <estimate number>,
  })
```

for getting the gas limit dynamically, use this before calling the actual method:

```
const estimateGas = await farmContract.estimateGas['depositEth']()
const tx = await farmContract.depositEth({
    gasLimit: estimateGas,
  })
```

Also, you can add new a bit margin to gasLimit using this:

```
export function calculateGasMargin(value: BigNumber, margin = 1000):BigNumber {
  return value.mul(BigNumber.from(10000).add(BigNumber.from(margin))).div(BigNumber.from(10000)) 
}
```

wrap `gasLimit` with `calculateGasMargin`:

```
{
    gasLimit: calculateGasMargin(estimateGas),
}
```